# visual studio android import cant resolved after update

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017

I updated Visual Studio, then my Android project had errors such as import could not be resolved. It could not be resolved to a text type. The type could not be resolved. Then I created a new project with the same settings. However, it had the same errors. It does not work because of the code, but maybe it knows who knows the code here.

```
package com.Android2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Android2 extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* Create a TextView and set its text to "Hello world" */
        TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello World!");
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code or imports...
I know it is hard work and a serious change when it comes to shortcuts, menus, overview, etc., but i would suggest to use android studio instead of visual studio if you only write android apps in java. I used visual studio too and switched to android studio.
Android Studio will give you more comfort than every other ide in programming android apps in java!

I know this problems you wrote about very well and had the same. Sry that this isnt a really answer of your problem and does not solves your concrete problem.

> Tips for solving, you probably already know:
>
> - reboot your pc and visual studio if you not already did
> - delete caches or other from visual studio
> - rebuilt/clean your project
> - not easy, but reinstall visual studio

I hope i could help anyway!